# Java Swing: Adding a JLabel to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm simply trying to add a JLabel to an existing JPanel. This seems really simple, and I've searched all around. I think that this is right, but the label is not appearing on my panel. Anybody see what I am missing? Thanks!

```
ResultsPanel myPanel = new ResultsPanel(pnlResults);  //pnlResults is an existing JPanel
myPanel.addLabel(pnlResults);

public class ResultsPanel extends JPanel {

    JPanel myPanel;

    public ResultsPanel(JPanel thisPanel) {
        myPanel = thisPanel;
    }

    public void addLabel(JPanel myResults) {
        JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("test", JLabel.LEFT);
        myPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(myLabel);        
    }

}
```

EDIT: In response to the immediate replies below, I agree that this seems to be total overkill. I went down this path because the following code also does not result in a JLabel being added to my JPanel:

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("test"); 
pnlResults.add(myLabel);
```

I would much rather use this code, so feel free to comment on this if you think it is more likely to work (with some modifications, of course).  Thanks again!

Comment: See my last comment on my post per your last edit

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I looked at your comment. I think that what I am doing in my edit is the same, no? My JPanel sits on a JDialog, which already exist (created by the GUI builder), so I don't need that part in my code. These two lines are simply part of the constructor for the JDialog Form. Am I following your suggestion correctly?

Comment: Could you post a little more of your code (you can take out some of the stuff non-related to the issue, only keep swing stuff)? That should help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be jumping through hoops just to do a basic thing; simply call

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Test text");//initialize the label
//do some stuff with label here maybe...
panel.add(label);//now add it
```

There is no need to make a class extends JPanel, and contain a JPanel; if a class extends JPanel, to get the JPanel instance, simply use this (so addLabel would instead do this.setLayout(blah)). But of course there is no need to even subclass JPanel for something as simple as adding a JLabel

Overall, here's pretty much the simplest swing application:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Basic Swing");//Make a frame
    frame.setSize(300, 300);//Give it a size
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);//Make it go away on close
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();//Make a panel
    frame.add(panel);//Add it to your frame

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello StackOverflow!");//Make a label
    panel.add(label);//Add it to the panel (which is on the frame)

    frame.setVisible(true);//Show the frame
```

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I tried this exact code (and just tried it again). Same result - no label.

Comment: @usr55410 See my edit, added a basic swing application, either compare yours with that and find your mistake, or simply add more of your code here

Comment: I got it. The problem wasn't with this code. My JPanel had to be set to FlowLayout. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it!

Comment: Ahh, ok, weird, that should be the default layout of a jpanel. Well anyways, good to know its all fixed, and glad I could sort've help :)

Comment: You totally helped. Your suggestion allowed me to stop focusing on writing unnecessary classes and look at other possible reasons. I would have spun my wheels for a long time otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you've extended from `JPanel`

Secondly, you've supplied you're own `JPanel`

Now, from your code snippet, there's no way to determine if either `ResultsPane` or `myPanel` have been added to a `Container` of any kind, but from what you're saying, I'd suggest that would be your primary problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want/need to have an actual JLabel object?  If not, you can label your panel as follow:

```
public void addLabel() {
    myPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("test"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("test text");
myLabel.setSize(myLabel.getPreferredSize());
panel.add(myLabel);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: Should be `getPreferredSize`