# JLabel will not update/ display. Initialization Issue?

Tags: java, swing

I know there are already many topics on this issue but I promise you I have exhausted the search.

At the opening of my application, the "ExampleGUI" window should display, when a Calendar button is clicked a Calendar Frame pops up and the user chooses a date, which is represented as a String. This string, along with some other information, is passed back to the ExampleGUI, as a new ExampleGUI. It will then go to the method updateDate, which should display the date that the user chose on the current frame, as a JLabel. However, no matter what I try, the JLabel will not display or will not update. I know about SetText, it's not currently included in my code but I have tried it and it doesn't work. I know it is passing the date correctly because System.out.println will work fine. If you have any help I will be forever grateful I am officially stumped.

**UPDATE**
Added the most pared down code I could make -- sorry the Calendar is so long, I couldn't take much out but I promise it is not the problem you just need it to run the GUI where the problem resides.

Thanks!

CODE:

Runner Class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Runner {

    public Runner() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GUI frame = new GUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

GUI Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public String newDate;
    public String myStartEnd;
    public String StartDate;
    public JLabel lblFinalStartDate;
    public JLabel lblFinalEndDate;

    public JPanel panelSearchCriteria = new JPanel();

    public GUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);



        GridBagConstraints gbc_panelSearchCriteria = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panelSearchCriteria.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panelSearchCriteria.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(panelSearchCriteria, gbc_panelSearchCriteria);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panelSearchCriteria = new GridBagLayout();
        panelSearchCriteria.setLayout(gbl_panelSearchCriteria);

        JButton btnChooseSDate = new JButton("Choose Date");
        btnChooseSDate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String source = new String("Start");
                Calndar startCal = new Calndar(source);
            }
        });
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnChooseSDate = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnChooseSDate.gridx = 1;
        gbc_btnChooseSDate.gridy = 1;
        panelSearchCriteria.add(btnChooseSDate, gbc_btnChooseSDate);
    }

    public GUI(String str, String soE) {
        this();
        updateDate(str, soE);
    }

    public void updateDate(String d, String se) {
        String tempdate = new String(d + "");
        String answer = new String(se + "");


        if (answer.equals("Start")) {
            StartDate = new String(tempdate + "");
            lblFinalStartDate = new JLabel(StartDate);

            GridBagConstraints gbc_lblFinalStartDate = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_lblFinalStartDate.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_lblFinalStartDate.gridx = 2;
            gbc_lblFinalStartDate.gridy = 1;
            this.panelSearchCriteria.add(lblFinalStartDate, gbc_lblFinalStartDate);

            System.out.println(lblFinalStartDate.getText());    
        }else{


        }
    }
}
```

Calendar Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;


public class Calndar extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    public int realDay, realMonth, realYear, currentMonth, currentYear;
    public JButton btnPrev = new JButton("<<");
    public JButton btnNext = new JButton(">>");
    public JLabel Monthlabel = new JLabel("");

    public int returnedDAY, returnedMONTH, returnedYEAR;
    public String FinalDate;


    public Calndar(String SoE) {
        setBounds(100, 100, 330, 430);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        realDay = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        realMonth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
        realYear = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
        currentMonth = realMonth;
        currentYear = realYear;

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);



        GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_label.gridx = 1;
        gbc_label.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(Monthlabel, gbc_label);



        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_scrollPane.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.setRowHeight(35);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][] { { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
                        { null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
                        { null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
                        { null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, },
                new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" }));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);


        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton btnChoose = new JButton("Select");
        btnChoose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                int col = table.getSelectedColumn();

                if (row == (-1) || col == (-1)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select a Date", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    returnDate(row, col);
                    GUI DS1 = new GUI(getFinalDate(), SoE);
                    dispose();
                }
            }
        });
        btnChoose.setMargin(new Insets(5, 20, 5, 20));
        panel_1.add(btnChoose);
        refreshCalendar(realMonth, realYear);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void refreshCalendar(int M, int Y) {
        int nod, som;
        Monthlabel.setText("July");


        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Y, M, 1);
        nod = cal.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        som = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                table.setValueAt(null, i, j);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= nod; i++) {
            int row = new Integer((i + som - 2) / 7);
            int column = ((i + som - 2) % 7);
            table.setValueAt(i, row, column);
        }

    }

    public String returnDate(int r, int c) {
        returnedYEAR = 2015;
        returnedMONTH = 7;
        returnedDAY = (int) table.getValueAt(r, c);

        FinalDate = new String("" + returnedYEAR + "-" + returnedMONTH + "-" + returnedDAY);

        return FinalDate;
    }

    public String getFinalDate(){
        if(FinalDate.equals(null)){
            String str = new String("None");
            return str;
        }else{
            return FinalDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ExampleGUI` should extend `JFrame` right? Do you currently get a window or what do you see?

Comment: You'll need to add the JLabel to the panel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103940/java-swing-adding-a-jlabel-to-a-jpanel and add the panel to the frame as well...

Comment: Sorry yes ExampleGUI extends JFrame, I rewrote this example code since my normal one is super long and I may have left some things out
Label is added see: panelSearchCriteria.add(lblFinalStartDate, gbc_lblFinalStartDate);

Comment: And I know the panel is in the frame because it holds many other components that will dsiplay

Comment: Time to do some debugging. Consider putting a border on the JLabel and on other components to make sure that it's not very small. Use a debugger to see if your variable states are what you expect them to be, consider paring down your code and your problem to the minimal amount that compiles, runs, and reproduces your problem, a [mcve], and post it here.

Comment: @BradyM: Where exactly, you specified the constraints values for `gbc_lblFinalStartDate`? Seems to me, the `weightx/weighty` are both `0`. You just initialized `GridBagConstraints` though you never did anythingy, seems like it is getting default values.

Comment: Basically I need to know where I should declare/intitialize the String and the JLabel in order for me to be able to edit them in the method updateDate

Comment: I specified constraints in the if statement right after GBC was declared, i just deleted them because they took up space.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I never thought of doing the mini code that still compiles, I will attempt that, it might take a few minutes though

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Any help would be appreciated

Comment: ................Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
  btnChoose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        int col = table.getSelectedColumn();

        if (row == (-1) || col == (-1)) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select a Date",
                 "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        } else {
           returnDate(row, col);
           GUI DS1 = new GUI(getFinalDate(), SoE);  // *****************
           dispose();
        }
     }
  });
```

You are creating a **new** GUI object, one completely distinct from the currently displayed GUI instance.

suggestions:

- The new window should not be a JFrame but should be a **modal** JDialog. If it is a modal dialog, it will freeze the calling code from the point that it is set visible, and then that code will resume flow once the dialog is no longer visible.
- Set this dialog visible from the original class, the GUI's ActionListener.
- Don't have Calndar object change anything in GUI. Rather in its action listener store the selected date (if anything is selected) in a field, and dispose of the dialog.
- Then the calling class, here GUI can query the Calndar object once it is no Calndar is longer visible, within GUI's select ActionListener, but after Calndar is set visible, and extract the selected date by calling a public getter method on the Calndar object.
- Then GUI can use this information to update its visualized data.
- Call revalidate and repaint after adding or removing components from a running GUI.
- In the future, try to use only 1 file for your example program.

For example. Note in the code below major changes are commented with `// !!`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

   private JPanel contentPane;

   public String newDate;
   public String myStartEnd;
   public String StartDate;
   public JLabel lblFinalStartDate;
   public JLabel lblFinalEndDate;

   public JPanel panelSearchCriteria = new JPanel();

   public GUI() {
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
      contentPane = new JPanel();
      setContentPane(contentPane);
      GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
      contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

      GridBagConstraints gbc_panelSearchCriteria = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc_panelSearchCriteria.gridx = 0;
      gbc_panelSearchCriteria.gridy = 0;
      contentPane.add(panelSearchCriteria, gbc_panelSearchCriteria);
      GridBagLayout gbl_panelSearchCriteria = new GridBagLayout();
      panelSearchCriteria.setLayout(gbl_panelSearchCriteria);

      JButton btnChooseSDate = new JButton("Choose Date");
      btnChooseSDate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String source = new String("Start");
            Calndar startCal = new Calndar(GUI.this, source); // !!
            startCal.setVisible(true); // !!
            String finalDate = startCal.getFinalDate();
            updateDate(finalDate, source); // !!
         }
      });
      GridBagConstraints gbc_btnChooseSDate = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc_btnChooseSDate.gridx = 1;
      gbc_btnChooseSDate.gridy = 1;
      panelSearchCriteria.add(btnChooseSDate, gbc_btnChooseSDate);
   }

   public GUI(String str, String soE) {
      this();
      updateDate(str, soE);
   }

   public void updateDate(String d, String se) {
      String tempdate = new String(d + "");
      String answer = new String(se + "");

      if (answer.equals("Start")) {
         StartDate = new String(tempdate + "");
         lblFinalStartDate = new JLabel(StartDate);

         GridBagConstraints gbc_lblFinalStartDate = new GridBagConstraints();
         gbc_lblFinalStartDate.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
         gbc_lblFinalStartDate.gridx = 2;
         gbc_lblFinalStartDate.gridy = 1;
         this.panelSearchCriteria.add(lblFinalStartDate, gbc_lblFinalStartDate);

         System.out.println(lblFinalStartDate.getText());

         revalidate(); // !!
         repaint(); // !!
      } else {

      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            GUI frame = new GUI();
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
}

class Calndar extends JDialog {  // !!

   private JPanel contentPane;
   private JTable table;
   public int realDay, realMonth, realYear, currentMonth, currentYear;
   public JButton btnPrev = new JButton("<<");
   public JButton btnNext = new JButton(">>");
   public JLabel Monthlabel = new JLabel("");

   public int returnedDAY, returnedMONTH, returnedYEAR;
   public String FinalDate;

   public Calndar(GUI gui, final String SoE) { // !!
      super(gui, "Calndar Title", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL); // !!
      setBounds(100, 100, 330, 430);
      contentPane = new JPanel();
      contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
      setContentPane(contentPane);

      GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
      realDay = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      realMonth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
      realYear = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
      currentMonth = realMonth;
      currentYear = realYear;

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
      gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
      gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
      gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
      gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
      panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

      GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc_label.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
      gbc_label.gridx = 1;
      gbc_label.gridy = 0;
      panel.add(Monthlabel, gbc_label);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
      GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc_scrollPane.gridwidth = 3;
      gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
      gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
      gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 1;
      panel.add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

      table = new JTable();
      table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      table.setRowHeight(35);
      table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
      table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
            { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, }, new String[] {
            "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" }));
      scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

      JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
      contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      JButton btnChoose = new JButton("Select");
      btnChoose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();

            if (row == (-1) || col == (-1)) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select a Date",
                     "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            } else {
               returnDate(row, col);
               // !! GUI DS1 = new GUI(getFinalDate(), SoE);
               dispose();
            }
         }
      });
      btnChoose.setMargin(new Insets(5, 20, 5, 20));
      panel_1.add(btnChoose);
      refreshCalendar(realMonth, realYear);
      // setVisible(true);
   }

   public void refreshCalendar(int M, int Y) {
      int nod, som;
      Monthlabel.setText("July");

      GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Y, M, 1);
      nod = cal.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      som = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            table.setValueAt(null, i, j);
         }
      }

      for (int i = 1; i <= nod; i++) {
         int row = new Integer((i + som - 2) / 7);
         int column = ((i + som - 2) % 7);
         table.setValueAt(i, row, column);
      }

   }

   public String returnDate(int r, int c) {
      returnedYEAR = 2015;
      returnedMONTH = 7;
      returnedDAY = (int) table.getValueAt(r, c);

      FinalDate = new String("" + returnedYEAR + "-" + returnedMONTH + "-"
            + returnedDAY);

      return FinalDate;
   }

   public String getFinalDate() {
      if (FinalDate.equals(null)) {
         String str = new String("None");
         return str;
      } else {
         return FinalDate;
      }
   }
}
```

Also:

- I wouldn't add a JLabel when adding the date in the main GUI. Rather I'd create a JLabel field, add it to the GUI initially, and then simply set its text when the need arises.